# How to make react-styleguide to support show documentation for JSDoc params?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-styleguidist

Whatever I'm doing I'm not able to generate docs for components that uses JSDoc.

For e.g.

The following code:

```
/**
 * @param {{name:string}} props
 * */
export function Button(props) {

}
```

Should show me:

[image]

To see the props I must use propTypes

```
Button.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
}
```

So, how to make `react-styleguidist` to work with JSdoc (or even kind of typescript).

A working example would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use @param when documenting props.

Here you can find more about how to use JSDoc tags:
https://react-styleguidist.js.org/docs/documenting.html#using-jsdoc-tags